# Why form1 also closes form2 whenever form1 is closed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have two form created in VS-2008, login_F and `switchBoard_F`. `login_F` is a login form for user which authenticate user's login and then open s`witchBoard_F` from the function:

Whenever `login_F`, is closed it also closes `switchBoard_F`. I want the s`witchBoard_F` to be open all the time and close the `login_F`, but I have no idea which code is closing my `switchBoard_F` while I close the `login_F`?

here is the code:

```
 Private Sub SaveUSerInfo()


    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_InsertLogReg", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@EmpID", My.Settings.UserID))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sHostName", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sUserName", System.Environment.UserName()))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApplicationName", My.Settings.gAppName))

    'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim newID As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) 'return LogRegID

    'get UserGroup
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT tblKOCEmp.EmpID, tblKOCEmp.Name, tblOrg.GroupName, tblOrg.Active"
    strSQL = strSQL + " FROM tblKOCEmp "
    strSQL = strSQL + " INNER JOIN tblOrg ON dbo.tblKOCEmp.OrgCode = dbo.tblOrg.OrgCode"
    strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE (dbo.tblOrg.Active = 1)"
    strSQL = strSQL + " AND (tblKOCEmp.EmpID =" + My.Settings.UserID + ")"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read
            If Not IsDBNull(dr.Item("Name")) Then
                My.Settings.UserName = (dr.Item("Name"))
                My.Settings.GroupName = (dr.Item("GroupName"))
            End If
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()

    My.Settings.LogRegID = newID 'store LogRegID to mySettings

    switchBoard_F.Show()
    login_F.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the closing of a form. In response at which user action do you execute this code?

Comment: It is because closing the main form also terminates the program.  Very simple to change in VB.NET.  Project + Properties, Application tab, change the Shutdown mode setting.

Comment: Is there a 'form.Hide()' method in VB.NET?

Comment: Steve: there is a code in the above procedure switchBoard_F.Show() and  login_F.Close(), Which show switchBoard_F and then suddenly close it. login_F is the start form.

Comment: ... and yes! there is an option in Project Properties in Application tab + shutdown mode whether to close the application by closing the start form OR last form close.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your case .. but  I think you can make your `switchBoard_F` form as your main form.

When you call `login_F` form you can hide the main form .. So when the user input right password you just close `login_F` form .. and if they didn't you may close both of them ..

Comment: Thanks matzone, steve,  Hans Passant,  Writwick.

Comment: @Jani .. have you figured this out ?

Comment: yes @matzone . The login_F.hide() did the trick. my login_F is the star form and the code was closing the said form. so the whole application was shutting down. I hide the login_F and keep the swithBoard_F open. on switchboard_F the code is closing/Exiting the application:

Comment: < Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
                Me.Close()
                Application.Exit()
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    End Sub >

Comment: Ooops.. its the code I paste here but it all mixed up in one sentence :) no idea how to write in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `switchBoard_F.ShowDialog();` instead of `switchBoard_F.Show();`.

BTW:
Closing main form will always result in closing app unless set differently in Project Properties

Comment: Thanks matzone, steve,  Hans Passant,  Writwick. Good idea to make the switchboard_F as start form and then hide the login form after user login successfully and then close the user form and un-hide the switchBoard_F again. OR just keep the login form open in hide mode and open the swithBoard_F after successful login (in this case) What would be preferred?

Comment: @ Peuczyński, switchBoard_F.ShowDialog() is just keeping the login_F open in background and keep the swithBoadr_F open as a dialog. I dont want the login_F open after user is logged in.

Comment: You didn't tell that before. In that case before `switchBoard_F.ShowDialog();` put `this.Hide()`

Comment: I am using VB.NET. I hide the by Login_F.Hide(). This form is the starting form and this was the main problem to shutting down my whole application. any how thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

make sure about login second form is not parent form

or you may use loginform.hide and onclosing event of second form, secondform.close

Comment: Thanks Jenit Shah. I use the hiding form technique

Comment: What do you mean by parent form?